# Proving a number is a factor of a in (a mod N)

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Suppose you had a very large composite number, which is the product of a couple large primes. Let's call this  $a = c_1c_2c_3c_4$ where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and $c_4$ are all primes.

If you calculated $d = a \pmod N$ where $N$ is another very large number is it possible to prove that $ c_1 \mid a$ without knowing what $a$ is? All you know in this situation is $d, N$ and $c_1$.

I hope this question makes sense, please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Generally only if $\,p = c_1\,$ divides $N$; otherwise $p$ is coprime to $N$ so invertible mod $N$ so the multiples of $p$ can take all values mod $N$ since $\, b  \equiv  (bp^{-1})p \pmod{\! N}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks! I guess that somewhat makes sense